# django 'too many SQL variables' error with ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a form with `ModelMultipleChoiceField` on it, and I am getting `'DatabaseError: too many SQL variables'` (using SQLite) when the user picks more than 1000 entries in the selection widget and posts the form.

The problem seems to be the method `clean` of `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, which tries to select objects from the database simply by the `IN` SQL clause (e.g. SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN (1,2,3)). When the number of numbers in the IN argument rises over 1000 the `too many SQL variables` happens.

I am using the most recent version of Django (1.5.dev17922), though I think it is irrelevant because similar issues happened even with older versions.

I have always worked around this problem by custom temporary models that I used for joins of more complex queries. But more and more it seems to me that, either there already is a systematic solution to this problem that I am missing (which I hope somebody could point out to me), or there at least needs to be a need for it -- how do you address similar situations? -- in which case I can start thinking how to propose something general that could later be incorporated into Django.

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

EDIT: I posted the same question to django-users ML, and quite a fruitful discussion got going; https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/aI7uO49UVRU

Comment: Maybe, override `clean` to split huge lists into small chunks, make few requests and then put data back together? It will not be sorted properly, but I don't think it's critical for the purpose of `clean`. Also, I think this is a bug, so creating a ticket for Django is recommended.

Comment: @ilvar Yeah, thanks, that's a good idea, but the thing is, to preserve all the other functionality that stems from the clean method, the clean method has to return a QuerySet. If it was implemented as a series of smaller data chunks as you suggest, this wouldn't be possible, as I think the QuerySet should be based on a database table so that it can be properly used by other parts of code (joins, aggregates, ...). Your way can surely work around that problem, though I am looking for a systematic solution.